# Are there any Node.JS IDE's that are REPL interactive and mainstain state like the node.js console does?

Tags: node.js, ide, read-eval-print-loop

I'm looking for an IDE or environment, or "graphical console" similar to ISE for PowerShell.
I want to work on some JavaScript but not have a new instance of a node runtime everytime. Just like in the console I want to be able to run some code here and there, and still have access to the variables from commands I ran a few minutes ago. Also i'd love one that also can take the JavaScript Objects or JSON and display them visually rather than just in plain text like the console does.

Is there any IDE for this sort of thing, or are all the Node environments build for starting a new Node instance everytime you run your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Javascript programmer, so I don't know exactly if this is what you are looking for, but you might check out [Cloud9 IDE](https://c9.io/). It's web-based, supports Node.js, and saves the exact state of your setup so you wouldn't need to restart anything every time you log in.

Comment: would it save the state of the variables etc?